# "phones in the dictionary that do not have acoustic models" montreal forced aligner

Tags: python, nlp, speech-recognition, kaldi

I try to follow the example in the documentation of [MFA](https://montreal-forced-aligner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html) :

I execute on my computer (windows 10, Python 3.9, pip 21.2.4):

```
pip install montreal-forced-aligner
mfa download acoustic english
```

Then, when I execute:

```
mfa align path/to/dataset path/to/lexicon.txt english path/to/output
```

I receive the next error message:

```
All required kaldi binaries were found!
Cleaning old directory!
INFO - Setting up corpus information...
INFO - Found old run with 1 rather than the current 3, setting to 1.  If you would like to use 3, re-run the command with --clean.
INFO - Number of speakers in corpus: 1, average number of utterances per speaker: 1.0
INFO - Parsing dictionary without pronunciation probabilities without silence probabilities
dictionary phones: {'AH2', 'K', 'AY0', 'IH2', 'OY0', 'EY1', 'AH1', 'AO1', 'UH0', 'OY2', 'EH0', 'T', 'AE2', 'F', 'EY0', 'W', 'IY1', 'AE0', 'P', 'ER0', 'D', 'IY0', 'V', 'OW2', 'NG', 'ER1', 'IH1', 'AE1', 'G', 'IY2', 'EH2', 'OW0', 'TH',
 'UW2', 'UW1', 'AH0', 'ZH', 'JH', 'Y', 'UH2', 'OY1', 'Z', 'B', 'EY2', 'AO0', 'IH0', 'OW1', 'UW0', 'ER2', 'N', 'UH1', 'AY2', 'CH', 'AY1', 'HH', 'AA2', 'AW2', 'EH1', 'M', 'S', 'DH', 'AO2', 'L', 'AW0', 'AA1', 'AA0', 'AW1', 'SH', 'R'}
model phones: set()
There were phones in the dictionary that do not have acoustic models: AA0, AA1, AA2, AE0, AE1, AE2, AH0, AH1, AH2, AO0, AO1, AO2, AW0, AW1, AW2, AY0, AY1, AY2, B, CH, D, DH, EH0, EH1, EH2, ER0, ER1, ER2, EY0, EY1, EY2, F, G, HH, IH0
, IH1, IH2, IY0, IY1, IY2, JH, K, L, M, N, NG, OW0, OW1, OW2, OY0, OY1, OY2, P, R, S, SH, T, TH, UH0, UH1, UH2, UW0, UW1, UW2, V, W, Y, Z, ZH
```

I already tried to run this line with a `clean` flag and uninstall and re-install the package, but nothing solved the problem. What should I do in that case?

Thanks!